# How much of the original Robocop's organic body is left?

Tags: robocop

I am excluding the remake from 2014, wherein one could exactly see how much is left as the suit unfolded itself.

In the original movies and TV shows the electro mechanical parts were firmly connected with the biological ones. Robocop had to take in food in the form of pap for babies, which has to be processed someway, maybe even discharged another.

Comment: Just the chin remains.

Comment: 50% of the remaining organic material is left, the other half is right.

Comment: I ve watched the 2nd episode of the tv series from 94, therein the creator of Robocop's so called neural matrix,dr.young appeared. Has anyone further info on this neural matrix and if it works with Murphy's brain together or replaced it?

Answer (score 19):

### Not much

> Tyler: [while creating RoboCop] We were able to save the left arm.
>
> Bob Morton: What? I thought we agreed on total body prosthesis. Now, lose the arm, okay?

As for what was left...[**this answer**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132891/how-many-human-body-parts-are-inside-robocop) over at our sister site Science Fiction & Fantasy has a full explanation.

- His brain and possibly elements of his spinal column
- His face and tongue (but not the underlying bone structure. It's overlaid onto a metal skull)
- Possibly his lungs
- Some form of digestive tract<sup>*</sup>

> <sup>*[**From the script**](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Robocop.pdf)</sup>
>
> Morton: How does he eat?
>
> Roosevelt: His digestive tract is extremely simple. This machine dispenses a rudimentary paste that sustains his organic systems.

Comment: I'd also add at least part of his stomach since he has to eat that paste to survive meaning the food has to go somewhere.

Comment: Possibly but there's no indication of how the digestion/excretion process occurs.

Comment: there's actually a scene where they talk about the digestion process, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Verhoeven's comments on the remake show us explicitly that Murphy's brain was not intact in the original movie:

> Somehow they seem to think that the lightness of, say, Total Recall and Robocop is a hindrance. So they take these somewhat absurd stories and make them much too serious. I think that is a mistake. Especially in Robocop when he awakens they gave him the same brain. He’s a horribly injured and amputated victim, which is horrifying and tragic from the very beginning. So we didn’t do that in Robocop. His brain is gone and he has only flashes of memory and needs to go to a computer to find out who he even is. I think by not having a robot brain, you make the movie much heavier and I don’t think that helps the movie in anyway. It becomes more silly or absurd, but in the wrong way. Both those movies needed the distance of satire or comedy to situate it for audiences. Playing it straight without any humour is a problem and not an improvement.

http://collider.com/paul-verhoeven-elle-robocop-reboot-interview/

Comment: Do you think he is saying there is only part of his brain left and filled up by robotic elements, or he has the full brain enhanced by robotic elements or a copy of his brain realized with robotic elements exclusively?

Comment: It's stated in one of the movies that RoboCop just has a piece of Murphy's brain, but the truthfulness of that statement is questionable. Of course, Murphy was shot in the head, so there was likely brain damage in any case.